# Connecting reactjs with nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mern

I have an app with front end react and backend node. The backend is tested with postman and working fine. the front  end ui is tested with static data. Now I have set up a proxy with the react part to connect to the backend node.

My react app is runnning on port 3000
my node is running on port 5000.

When I request  a route on my backend  from my front end the app does not utilize the proxy set up Instead it gives me a Bad request error.

My  front end is in client folder .Please help.
the project can be found on the following github link

https://github.com/prashantbhat84/mern-contactkeeper

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a cross-origin problem. There are two ways to solve cross-origin problems in node server,

1. Using cors node module

First install cors module. `npm install cors`

and then use it inside your app

```
const Express       = require("express");
const BodyParser    = require("body-parser");
const Cors          = require("cors");

const app = Express();
app.use(Cors());

app.use(BodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(BodyParser.json());

app.listen(3001, 'localhost', (err) => {
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
    console.log("Server listen port 8083");
});
```

2. simply use following headers

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE");
    next();
});
```

Comment: Hello @Tenusha, Did what you mentioned . No change

Comment: @prashant bhat Are you still getting the same issue or different one?

Comment: Same http status 400

Answer (score 0):

NPM uses a configuration file and it can be added to via the command line npm config set. The key to getting it right is the spelling of the settings. This has bit me so many times now! Getting npm to work behind a proxy requires setting the proxy and https-proxy settings. The key is noticing the - (dash) is not an _ (underscore).

Open an command prompt or terminal session and run the following commands to configure npm to work with your web proxy. The commands use domain_name.com as the address and 8080 as the port.

```
npm config set proxy http://domain_name.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://domain_name.com:8080
```

Comment: No change.The proxy from localhost:3000 to 5000 is not happening

Comment: You need to add some Rewrite rules.  Please refer this url : https://steve.fi/Software/node-reverse-proxy/ I hope it will be works